# How to access VM inside VNET from a Azure Linux Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Scenario:

1. Azure Linux VM created inside VNET (with subnet)
2. Oracle database created on the Linux VM
3. Azure Linux Web App created outside the VNET

Query:
How can my Linux Web App connect to the database on VM within VNET from outside and get a result set back?
So both inbound and outbound from VNET point of view - only to the webapp.

Went through Azure docs about Private endpoint and VNET Integration but am still not sure whether these individually or together will be needed to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you just need to connect your WebApp to Azure Linux VM with Oracle DB created inside VNET in secure way.

I would recommend you to integrate your WebApp with an existing Azure VNET with Azure Linux VM.

1. In your WebApp go to "Networking" and then select "Click here to configure".
   [image]
2. Select "Add VNet" and choose VNET with Azure Linux VM and then Subnet.
   [image]
3. In the Configuration of your WebApp set Oracle connection string with private IP address of Azure Linux VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enable-vnet-integration

Comment: Hi @Andriy Bilous
Thanks. While adding the VNET, I have to mention the subnet but I am not able to use the "default" subnet (where the VM is hosted). Its asking me to create a new one. If I do so, can my webapp still use the private ip of VM to connect?

Comment: Yes, you have to create new subnet to connect WebApp into it.
Azure resources in different Subnets(same VNET) can communicate between each other(If custom firewall rules are not applied).